# ASP.NET MVC Autofac Singleton

Tags: asp.net-mvc, singleton, autofac

I am using autofac with ASP.NET MVC, using the Repository Pattern.
I have a class like this

```
 public class IoC : ContainerBuilder
{

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private readonly static IoC _instance = new IoC();

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private static object _lock;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IContainer _componentsContainer;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public static IoC Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IContainer GetComponentsContainer()
    {
        if (_componentsContainer == null)
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                if (_componentsContainer == null)
                    _componentsContainer = this.Build();
            }
        }

        return _componentsContainer;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public T Resolve<T>() where T : class
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().Resolve<T>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ILifetimeScope BeginLifetimeScope()
    {
        return GetComponentsContainer().BeginLifetimeScope();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IoC()
    {
        _lock = new object();
        ConfigureDependencies();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private void ConfigureDependencies()
    {
        //Configure all your depedendencies here!!

        //Database connection
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pixie"].ConnectionString;
        this.Register(c => new SqlConnection(connectionString)).As<IDbConnection>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        //Database Connection OrmLite
        OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqlServerDialect.Provider;
        //Repository
        this.RegisterType<Repository>().As<IRepository>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

}
```

And in my Application_Start method in Global.asax I have the following

```
protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            // Register your MVC controllers.
             IoC.Instance.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
              IoC.Instance.RegisterModelBinders(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            IoC.Instance.RegisterModelBinderProvider();
            IoC.Instance.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
            IoC.Instance.RegisterModule<AutofacWebTypesModule>();
            IoC.Instance.RegisterSource(new ViewRegistrationSource());


            var MVCControllersResolver = new AutofacDependencyResolver(IoC.Instance.GetComponentsContainer());
}
```

My Repository is as follows

```
 public class Repository : DataConnection, IRepository
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    public Repository(IDbConnection connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
    }

    public IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        return Connection;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Select<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> objFunc) where T : new()
    {

        // Orm Lite Version 
        return Connection.Select<T>(objFunc);




       }
}
```

where DataConnection is a class like this

```
public class DataConnection : IDisposable
{
    #region Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    private IDbConnection _connection;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    protected IDbConnection Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if (_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Connecting)
                _connection.Open();

            return _connection;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connection"></param>
    public DataConnection(IDbConnection connection)
    {
        _connection = connection;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Close the connection if this is open
    /// </summary>
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            _connection.Close();
    }
}
```

And my controllers are initialized like this

```
   public class QueryController : Controller
{
    private IRepository Repository;
    public QueryController(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }
public ActionResult Index()
    {

        IEnumerable<Product> products = Repository.Select<Product>(q=>q.Id == 1);
        return View(products);
    }
}
```

That way I initialize my Repository and my controllers. Now I have the following problem.

I have a class (model) like this

```
public class OSADCOL
    {

        public int id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TBLid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> LOVid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> COLGRPid { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> TabCOLGRPid { get; set; }
}
```

This class get's its data from the database via requests like this in the controller

```
IEnumerable<OSQDCOL> osqdcols = Connection.Select<OSQDCOL>("TBLid = @id", new {id = Id });
```

or

```
IEnumerable<OSQDCOL> osqdcols = Repository.Select<OSQDCOL>("TBLid = @id", new {id = Id });
```

Data like this is being used throughout my app in many controllers and is just readonly. Instead of making a new request on the database for every HTTPrequest that needs this data, is there a way to initialise these objects once on Application start? May the singleton pattern is required but I don't know how to implement it using autofac.
Any Ideas?

Comment: The parameter "Id" is fixed accross all controllers?

Comment: O yes, I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register a delegate and resolve the connection inside. This will delay the query until the first resolve. In your controllers you just add List. If this needs to be done once per request and you don't want it to live the entire time change .SingleInstance() to .InstancePerHttpRequest()

```
IoC.Instance.Register(c =>
{
   var conn = c.Resolve<Connection>();
   return conn.Select<OSQDCOL>("TBLid = @id", new {id = Id }).ToList();
}).As<List<OSQDCOL>>().SingleInstance();

public QueryController(IRepository repository, List<OSQDCOL> myCachedData)
{

}
```

You might also look at setting up a CacheService like so:

```
builder.Register<CacheService>()
  .SingleInstance()
  .OnActivated(x => x.Instance.InitCache())
  .AutoActivate()
  .As<ICacheService>()
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have 2 questions. The first is which is the place to put this code? In the Application_start method in Global.asax or in ConfigureDependencies method in IoC ? The second is, how am I going to combine this SingleInstance object with the cacheservice? I don't know many things on caching in MVC and I was wondering whether it's being possible to cache this object for a specific time period.

Comment: @ChristophAdamakis In ConfigureDependencies CacheService would be a new class you write, to contain any long living data. Since your inside MVC I would recommend using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Has sliding expirations, and other features.

Answer (score 0):

If your "Connection" is usable during the application startup and the "Id" parameter is always fixed, you can use the following line:

Declare a interface like :

```
public interface IOsqlcols : IEnumerable<OSQDCOL>
{}
```

In the registration process, you have to register your interface like this:

```
var rows = Connection.Select<OSQDCOL>("TBLid = @id", new {id = Id });
IoC.Instance.RegisterInstance(rows).As<IOsqlcols>();
```

And then, you can resolve your interface in the parameter of your controller

```
public MyController(IOsqlcols osqlcols)
{
    this.osqlcols = osqlcols;
}
```

By the way,  from my point of view, I won't try to override the ContainerBuilder with my own class.  Use it as it is.

Comment: Unfortunately the "Connection" is not usable during the application start up. My controllers are using the repository pattern which uses autofac to get a reference on the Connection. I have updated my post with the missing info.

Comment: And the respository can be different depending on the controller?

Comment: No, no, There exists only one repository with various methods which is being used in order to get access (and data of course ) from the database. I added an action on the Controller code snippet that shows how the controller uses the Repository.